# Trying to create a very simple quiz using html, js, and forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need it to display green if question 1 is "1", or question 2 is "4". Red otherwise when mark quiz is called. Where am I going wrong with this code? js is located in an external file.

Html:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Questions</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="1">
            Water is
            <ol>
                <li> Wet</li>
                <li> Ordinary</li>
                <li>Purify </li>
                <li> Water</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form name="question1" action="www.quizMarker.ca">
                <input type="text" name="quest1" placeholder="Enter Answer"> 
            </form>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="2">
            Fire is
            <ol>
                <li> Wet</li>
                <li> Ordinary</li>
                <li>Purify </li>
                <li> Hot</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form name="question2" ction="www.quizMarker.ca">
                <input type="text" name="quest1" placeholder="Enter Answer"> 
            </form>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="markQuiz()">Mark Quiz</button>
```

js:

```
function markQuiz()
{
var q1 = document.forms['question1'];
var q1Ans = q1.elements['quest1'].value;

var q2 = document.forms['question2'];
var q2Ans = q2.elements['quest2'].value;

var row1 = document.getElementById("1");
var row2 = document.getElementById("2");

if(q1Ans = "1")
    {
        row1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
else()
    {
        row1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

if(q2Ans = "4")
    {
        row2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
else()
    {
        row2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Right now markQuiz is not doing anything when called. Also if there is a simpler way to accomplish this task, suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: First off your ids must start with a letter not a number

Comment: Your syntax is invalid: `  } else() {`

Comment: `=` always assigns value so returns to true. use `===`

Comment: and no `()` after else

Comment: Even after these changes the quiz does not function as it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

you may need "==" or "===" instead of "=", which mean assign.

```
if(a = "1") {
  //code here always execute
}
if(a === "1") {
  //code here only execute when a is String with value "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra = symbol in your code

```
if(q1Ans = "1")
    {
        row1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
```

correct syntax is:

```
if(q1Ans == "1")
        {
            row1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the changes i made

```
function markQuiz()
{
var q1Ans = document.forms['question1'].quest1.value;
var q1Ans = document.forms['question2'].quest2.value;

// PLease change the ids of the td ttag
var row1 = document.getElementById("table1");
var row2 = document.getElementById("table2");

if(q1Ans === "1")
    {
        row1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
else
    {
        row1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

if(q2Ans === "4")
    {
        row2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
else
    {
        row2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work even after this change and press the mark quiz button

Comment: Please check the above answer, i made some changes to the selector query.

Comment: I have a feeling it's something to do with the button, it's still not working

Comment: Just to be sure, have you properly linked the external js file??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5owzscxx/4/  Yeah thats not an issue. Even running it in JSFiddler does not work

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle, there was issue with external js file linking so i added the js within <script> tag and the name of second input was quest1 instead of quest2. here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/5owzscxx/21/